# How to remove outer array using PHP

Tags: php

Currently I am getting the following output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => car
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => bike
    )

)
```

what I need is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => car
    [1] => bike
)
```

What I have tried:

```
print_r(reset($get_vehicle_names));
print_r(current($get_vehicle_names));

foreach($get_vehicle_names as $key => $value)
{
    $newArr[$key] = $value;             
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `$arr_output  = array_column($arr, 'name')` this is it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `array_column`, you will get what you want.

```
$arr = array(
        array("name" => "car"),
        array("name" => "bike")
    );
$arr_output = array_column($arr, 'name');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr_output);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => car
    [1] => bike
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
$newArr[$key] = $value['name']; // You just need to store $value['name']
}
print '<pre>';print_r($newArr);
```